# What replaced the deprecated PayPal Adaptive payments API

Tags: paypal

My team and I had the PayPal Adaptive payments API integrated into our web app (which allows a user to withdraw funds, as they can sell items in the market place), and we were testing recently before launching. We began receiving the following error:

```
errorId = 580001;
        message = "Invalid request: Unilateral payment is deprecated.";
        parameter =             (
            "Unilateral payment is deprecated.",
            "One or more receiver account is unconfirmed/does not exist."
        );
        severity = Error;
```

Looking at the documentation it states that it is now deprecated: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Does anyone know what has replaced this API? Is it the Payouts API? Or does anyone know any alternative APIs for what we are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old Adaptive APIs did many things, and some of the features like chained payments do not have a new replacement. For the use case of sending money from your account to an email address using PayPal, if that's all you're asking about, then yes the Payouts API should be used now. You can [request access here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/standard/#link-getaccesstopaypalpayouts).

(There's also an even more advanced solution called [Hyperwallet](https://www.hyperwallet.com/), used by larger companies who need multiple ways to send money globally.)

Comment: Alas, between Dec 2021 and July 2022, it seems the PayOuts API might also have been withdrawn as the "request access here" link above points to a dead page!

Comment: URL of the payouts doc is now https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/standard/#link-getaccesstopaypalpayouts .....